# macOS, PyCharm, 2.7 python interpreter - How to I append a specific character after every occurrence of a given character?

Tags: regex, macos, python-2.7, pycharm

Suppose I have a variable with a raw string assignment, as shown below.

```
TrackVariable = r'one\two\three'
```

`TrackVariable` will constantly change throughout the code; however, it will always be a raw string that may *or may not* contain any number of `\` characters.

The raw string may even contain several `\` characters in a row, as in the following example

```
TrackVariable = r'one\\\two\\\three'
```

If I manually name a file `one\two\three.txt` and drag it into a terminal window, it gets automatically formatted as `one\\two\\three.txt`

If I manually name a file `one\\two\\three.txt` and drag it into a terminal window, it gets automatically formatted as `one\\\\two\\\\three.txt`

And, finally, If I manually name a file `one\\\two\\\three.txt` and drag it into a terminal window, it gets automatically formatted as `one\\\\\\two\\\\\\three.txt`

**How do I write a regex (or some other kind of code) that automatically re-formats the variables in the manner above. I assume that there is some kind of code that will append a `\` after every occurrence of a `\`. How do I do this?**

I am asking this question because I need to run a shell script in which `TrackVariable` will be part of a file path.

**Edit:** There are a number of other characters that must be escaped when running a shell script. Is there a simple way to automatically escape any characters that need escaping for a variable with a raw string assignment?

Here are the characters—with each one being separated by a space—that need escaping (I already know how to escape new lines)

```
| & ; ( ) < > ~ * ? ! $ # [ ] { } ' " `
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can't believe I literally just figured it out, and it was much simpler than I thought. I literally spent hours trying trying to do this and by sheer coincidence found the answer a minute after posting the question.

```
import re

TrackVariable = r'D\o y\\ou g\\\et it y\\\\et?'

TrackVariable = re.sub(r'(\\)', r'\1\\', TrackVariable)

print(TrackVariable)
```

Prints --> `D\\o y\\\\ou g\\\\\\et it y\\\\\\\\et?`